# Pygame Return Width of Image

Tags: python, width, pygame

I'm very new to Python and Pygame but just experimenting for now and trying to create a health bar for a character. The health bar should start as the width of the character image but for some reason it's returning zero.

Please can you advise where I'm going wrong? I think it could be something to do with it returning as an integer.

I also tried self.image.get_width() with no luck.

```
class Player(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
    self.imagerect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.direction = 'right'
    self.imagewidth = self.imagerect.width
    self.health = 100

def healthbar(self, healthvalue):
    healthwidth = (self.imagewidth / 100) * healthvalue
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (self.x, self.y -10, healthwidth, 10), 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (self.x, self.y -10, healthwidth, 10), 0)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Division behaves differently in 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: I'm using 2.x because I couldn't get 3.x to work with Pygame on OS X.

I think I've just solved my own question though... wrapping the width in float() seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x `/` is the floor division operator - the equivalent of `//` in Python 3.x.

For example - `6/2 == 3`, `7/2 == 3`, `8/4 == 2`, `8/3 == 2`.

```
x/y == how many times y fits into x
```

As you noticed, changing one of the operands to a `float` changes the operation to normal division.

Comment: Thank you! Easy when you know how...!